# On studying the behaviour of a series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

> Study for which $\alpha, \beta \geq0$, the series
> $$\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{(log(n))^\alpha}{n^\beta}$$
> converges.

To study this series I have multiple results about non-negative series. Using the logarithm criterion I have shown that, if

$$\beta < 1 \implies \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{(log(n))^\alpha}{n^\beta} <\infty$$
$$\beta > 1 \implies \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{(log(n))^\alpha}{n^\beta} = \infty$$

Then I would like to study the case in which $\beta=1$.

I see that the series, remains non-negative and that the [ration test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_test) nor the [logarithm criterion](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Logarithmic_convergence_criterion) tell me anything about the behaviour about the series, since I used it earlier to discuss for $\beta$.

Next, I tried using the [Direct comparison test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_comparison_test), and I just wanted to see if my next argument was correct.

Since,

$$\frac{1}{n}\leq \frac{(log(n))^\alpha}{n}, \hspace{2mm} \forall n\geq 1$$

and the harmonic series $\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{n}$ diverges, hence $\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{(log(n))^\alpha}{n}$ diverges for all $\alpha$.

Answer (score -1):

I have observed that my claim about $\frac{1}{n}\leq \frac{(log(n))^\alpha}{n}, \hspace{2mm} \forall n\geq 1$ is not true for all $n$, but for a finite number of them. Is my argument still holding?